# Cakephp 2.6 how do I return to the main application after entering a plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, url-routing, cakephp-2.6

I am using Luis Dias' Report Manager Plugin to generate some quick reports for an application I am developing. From my application dashboard I enter the plugin using the following:

```
        <td style="text-align:center"> 
        <button style="height:75px; width:175px; background-color:BurlyWood; font-size:20px; font-family:Verdana"
         onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'report_manager'
         ,'action'=>'reports'))?>'">Report  Management</button>
```

I'd really like to open the Report Generator Wizard in a new window but that's a different issue..

Once I am done with the report generator I'd like to return to my dashboard in my application. However, I am now in the Plugin's domain and can't figure out a command to "route" me back to the calling application.

Thanks in advance

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 'escape' from a plugin when routing you need to pass `plugin => false` in the route array. For example:-

```
$this->Html->url([
    'controller' => 'pages', 
    'action' => 'view', 
    1, 
    'plugin' => false
]);
```

If you don't pass the `plugin` attribute it assumes you want to remain in the context of the current plugin. You need to be careful with this wherever you use links where plugins are in use.